# How to go back to the previous action using Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

For my web app project, I'm trying to implement a logic that displays a link if the previous action is Create. How can I determine what the previous action is using Entity Framework Core? I want to use this logic in my razor view.

Comment: Why you dont use viewbag to show that link in view? if you insert command runs viewbag = 1 else viewbag = 0 and in razor if viewbag = 1 show action link

Comment: Not sure I understand. My question is how do I find the previous action?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you really to do? You need to redirect or just know the url refferent?

Comment: I want to know what the previous url is.

Comment: So just use `string previousUrl = this.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Referer"].ToString();`

Comment: Can you give me an example of this function used in the razor view?